# "Stage" package not compiling. OS X 10.8

Tags: simulation, stage, macos-mountain-lion, macosx, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I am trying to install ROS on my Mac with OS X 10.8, XCode 5.0.2, The package "Stage" fails to compile in the process. It says  the following : (stream gisted at https://gist.github.com/karthikkovalam/11205070)

```
-- checking for one of the modules 'playercore>=2.1.0'
--   * Player not detected. If Player is installed but not detected, check your PKG_CONFIG_PATH.
```

I am not sure on how to handle this. I tried to install PlayerStage on my machine with "brew install player" and it failed with the following error stream. (Gisted at https://gist.github.com/karthikkovalam/11205137)

Please help in this regards. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156516/%22stage%22-package-not-compiling.-os-x-10.8/) by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-04-23**:
I'll take a look soon.

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-04-23**:
For the record, Iam using stage on 10.9 just fine, no problems as far as I could remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The player not found is a red herring, the real problem is that it cannot find `libtool`:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LTDL_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /Users/Siva/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage
   used as include directory in directory /Users/Siva/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage/libstage
   used as include directory in directory /Users/Siva/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage/libstage
   used as include directory in directory /Users/Siva/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage/examples/ctrl
   used as include directory in directory /Users/Siva/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage/examples/ctrl
   used as include directory in directory /Users/Siva/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage/examples/ctrl
   used as include directory in directory /Users/Siva/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage/examples/ctrl
   used as include directory in directory /Users/Siva/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage/examples/ctrl
   used as include directory in directory /Users/Siva/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage/examples/ctrl
   used as include directory in directory /Users/Siva/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage/examples/ctrl
   used as include directory in directory /Users/Siva/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage/examples/ctrl
   used as include directory in directory /Users/Siva/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage/examples/ctrl
   used as include directory in directory /Users/Siva/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage/worlds/benchmark
   used as include directory in directory /Users/Siva/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage/worlds/benchmark
LTDL_LIB
    linked by target "stage" in directory /Users/Siva/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage/libstage
```

This is the code which looks for those variables:

https://github.com/ros-gbp/stage-release/blob/upstream/CMakeLists.txt#L75-77

I cannot reproduce this problem on my machine though, so I'm not sure what is causing your problem.

Player not build I can reproduce, but that is something you would need to take up on the `homebrew-simulation` issue tracker:

https://github.com/osrf/homebrew-simulation/issues

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on 2014-04-23**:
Works after I installed libtool. As you told, that was a red herring. Thanks a lot.